# Is there a way to aggregate an xarrray DataArray by calculating the mode for each cell along the time dimension?

Tags: python, python-xarray

In the `xarray` python package, it is possible to reduce a DataArray's data by applying a function along some dimension (most commonly along the time dimension). Build-in functions include, among others, mean, min and max. I.e.:

```py
DataArray.mean(dim = 'time')
DataArray.min(dim = 'time')
DataArray.max(dim = 'time')
```

As far as I can see, there is no build-in way to calculate the mode in the same way. Is there a way to this otherwise, for example with the 'help' of other packages?

That is, some function that would be equivalent to:

```py
DataArray.mode(dim = 'time')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap Scipy's mode function using Xarray's `apply_ufunc`. More examples of how to use `apply_ufunc` can be found [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/computation.html#wrapping-custom-computation).

```
def _mode(*args, **kwargs):
    vals = scipy.stats.mode(*args, **kwargs)
    # only return the mode (discard the count)
    return vals[0].squeeze()


def mode(obj, None):
    # note: apply always moves core dimensions to the end
    # usually axis is simply -1 but scipy's mode function doesn't seem to like that
    # this means that this version will only work for DataArray's (not Datasets)
    assert isinstance(obj, xr.DataArray)
    axis = obj.ndim - 1
    return xr.apply_ufunc(_mode, obj,
                          input_core_dims=[[dim]],
                          kwargs={'axis': axis})
```

A quick example using xarray's tutorial datasets:

```
ds = xr.tutorial.load_dataset('air_temperature')

mode(ds, dim='time')
```

yields:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (lat: 25, lon: 53)
Coordinates:
  * lat      (lat) float32 75.0 72.5 70.0 67.5 65.0 ... 25.0 22.5 20.0 17.5 15.0
  * lon      (lon) float32 200.0 202.5 205.0 207.5 ... 322.5 325.0 327.5 330.0
Data variables:
    air      (lat, lon) float32 271.5 272.4 272.5 272.1 ... 296.9 296.9 296.79
```